# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when destructing props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, destructuring

I have a local json file as part of my React app. Which is structured as follows:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "company": "Photosnap",
  "logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": true,
  "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
  "role": "Frontend",
  "level": "Senior",
  "postedAt": "1d ago",
  "contract": "Full Time",
  "location": "USA Only",
  "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "company": "Manage",
  "logo": "./images/manage.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": true,
  "position": "Fullstack Developer",
  "role": "Fullstack",
  "level": "Midweight",
  "postedAt": "1d ago",
  "contract": "Part Time",
  "location": "Remote",
  "languages": ["Python"],
  "tools": ["React"]
},
```

As part of my React app I have a job list component and a job card component.  The idea is that that the card will render like this [image: Job Card] So what I am trying to do is render the buttons that are on the right had side of the card.
The code for the job card is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import CustomButton from '../../custom-button/custom.button.component';
import './job-card.styles.css';

const JobCard = ({company, position, postedAt, contract, location, logo, featured, new:    newJob, languages}) => (

<div className="container">
  <div className='card'>
    <div className='companyName'>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="100" height="100"></img>
    </div>
    <div className='content'>
      <div className='newFeatured'>
        <h2>{company}</h2>
        { newJob ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
        {featured ? <button className='myDarkButton'>Featured</button> : null }
        </div>
        <h1>{position}</h1>
        <div className='details'>
            <h3>{postedAt} &#183;</h3>
            <h3>{contract} &#183;</h3>
            <h3>{location}</h3>
        </div>
        {languages.map((language) =>
        <CustomButton>{language}</CustomButton>
        )}
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 )

export default JobCard;
```

My job listings component code is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './job-listing.styles.css';
import JobCard from '../job-card/job-card.component.jsx/job-card.component';
import { Component } from 'react';


class JobListing extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        jobs: []
    }
  };

    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({jobs: data}))

    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.jobs.map(({id,...otherJobProps}) =>(
            <JobCard key={id} {...otherJobProps} />
            ))}
        </div>

        )
      }
    }

   export default JobListing;
```

The error I am getting relates to the languages prop in the card component.  As it is an array I am trying to destructuring it without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's the `map` you've said it is, the problem is that you have at least one object that doesn't have a `languages` property — e.g., the data you're receiving sometimes leaves it off. The two objects in your sample JSON have it, but apparently, not all do.

How you handle it is up to you.

1. You could default it when destructuring by adding `= []` after `languages` in the destructuring in the parameter list.

   ```
   const JobCard = ({company, /*...*/, languages = []) => (
   ```
2. You could avoid calling `map` in the JSX when `languages` is falsy:

   ```
   {languages && languages.map((language) =>
   <CustomButton>{language}</CustomButton>
   )}
   ```

---

Side note: You'll need a `key` property on those `CustomButton`s you're creating in the `map` callback.